# Low quality audit tells you the answer

Tags: discussion, review-audits

So, I was in the low quality queue, and I came across a particularly easy audit.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4053045

One part of it that got my attention was this warning which essentially tells you straight out to recommend deletion:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

Are you meant to see those messages on audits?  Do they make audits too easy?

Comment: They really want to make sure that you are paying attention!

Comment: No. They make audits more realistic.

Comment: So, you are paying attention. Goal achieved!

Comment: ^just tracked down this question again to say exactly what LowerClassOverflowian has already said. I just had a high quality audit with the message shown